# How to access access of another model relationship from a model relationship in nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 models.

1 creative.js :

```
var creativeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: {type: String, required: true, validate: lengthValidator },
 desc: {type: String },
 video_format: { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'VideoFormat' }
});     

return this.find(criteria)

 .populate('video_format')
 .populate('order')
 .sort({'createdDate': -1}) // sort by date
 .limit(options.perPage)
 .skip(options.perPage * options.page)
 .exec(cb);
```

2 : order.js

```
var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: {type: String, required: true, validate: lengthValidator},
 desc: {type: String },
 creative: { type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Creative'}
}); 

  return this.find(criteria)
   .populate('creative') 
   .sort({'createdDate': -1}) // sort by date
   .limit(options.perPage)
   .skip(options.perPage * options.page)
   .exec(cb);
```

3 : video_format.js

```
var videoFormatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: {type: String, required: true, validate: lengthValidator},
 creatives: [{ type : mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Order'}]
});


 return this.find(options)
 .sort({'createdDate': -1}) // sort by date
 .populate('creatives')
 .exec(cb);
```

And all populations are  ok.

I accessing to video_format from creative.

```
<%= creative.video_format.title %>
```

I accessing to creative from order

```
<%=  order.creative.title %>
```

But I not accessing to video_format from order.

```
*<%=  order.creative.video_format.title %>*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mongoose only supports one level of population. You may try some 3rd party plugins for nested population.

Check this one: https://github.com/buunguyen/mongoose-deep-populate